# Why without `max-width` in the root container `display: flex` in the child element makes the root container occupy 100% of the width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vuetify.js

Sorry for a possibly silly question: Why without `max-width` of the root container (`document-list-item_container`) `display: flex` of the child makes the root container occupy 100% of the width? And to avoid 100% width, do I have to use `max-width` in the main container (`document-list-item_container`)?

When I use `max-width` in the root container (document-list-item_container) everything is fine, the red outlined element to which Flex is applied.

[image: When I use max-width in the root container]

If you remove `max-width` from the root container, then, as I wrote above, it becomes full-width, as below:

[image: If you remove max-width from the root container]

```css
.v-card {
  min-width: 350px;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  border: solid 1px #4a4a4a !important;
}

.document-item-id {
  background-color: #cccccc !important;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


.document-item__list {
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.document-list-item_container {}

.document-item__text-value {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.5.5/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div data-app="true" class="v-application v-application--is-ltr theme--light" id="app">
  <div class="v-application--wrap">
    <main class="v-main" style="padding: 0px;" data-booted="true">
      <div class="v-main__wrap">
        <div class="container container--fluid">


          <div class="document-list-item_container mw-400">
            <div class="elevation-0 ma-2 pa-2 v-card v-sheet theme--light">
              <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="pa-0 col col-6">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="v-image v-responsive ma-0 theme--light" cover="" style="height: 210px; max-width: 160px;">
                      <div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div>
                      <div class="v-image__image v-image__image--cover" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/halcyon.png&quot;); background-position: center center;"></div>
                      <div class="v-responsive__content" style="width: 300px;"></div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-left text-body-2 col col-6">
                  <div class="px-2 document-item-id">ID: 0</div>
                  <ul class="pa-0 document-item__list">
                    <li class="document-item__text-value">
                      lorem ipsum
                    </li>
                    <li class="document-item__text-value">

                    </li>
                    <li class="document-item__text-value">
                      lorem ipsum
                    </li>
                    <li class="document-item__text-value">

                    </li>
                    <li class="document-item__text-value">
                      lorem ipsum
                    </li>
                    <li class="document-item__text-value">
                      lorem ipsum
                    </li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="v-card__actions pt-12">
                <div class="text-caption text-left">
                  Folder/ <br> FileName.pdf
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to the codesandbox: [https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-r53c1?file=/src/layout.vue:417-445)

Thank you,  have a good day

Comment: Your question is mainly about CSS & HTML, try to recreate the issue with minimal CSS & HTML as of right now, Your screenshots don't match the code snippet and it doesn't illustrate the issue, Doubt anyone would want to div into VueJs to answer a simple CSS question.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying styles from vuetify, for example:

```
.col-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

... and may be somewhere else... could you check in devtools?
you shouldn't use this or overwrite with custom styles.
Will be better enable `flex-grow: 1;` for right column with text. So, text will fill all available space.